# Counter not increasing in async map function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I am working with mongodb and nodejs. I have an array of customers I have to create each inside database.

```
const promises2 = customers.map(async customer => {
      if (!customer.customerId) {
        const counter = await Counter.findOne({ type: "Customer" });
        console.log({counter});
        const payload = {
          customerId: counter.sequence_value,
        };
        await Customer.create(payload);
        await Counter.findOneAndUpdate({ type: "Customer" }, { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } });
      }
    });
    await Promise.all([...promises2]);
```

The issue is counter is not increasing every time. I am getting same counter in all the created customers. What is the issue here?

Issue is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58504988/async-await-not-work-properly-inside-map-function) but don't have an answer.

Comment: This is what happening https://jsfiddle.net/hafcsgoz/. It is resolving promises in parallel. So first it finds all the counter and then updates all at once. This is ridiculous.

Comment: FYI, there was a really badly misworded part of my answer I've just fixed, in the paragraph starting "The overall operation..." :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that all the calls overlap. Since the first thing they each do is get the current counter, they all get the same counter, then try to use it. Fundamentally, you don't want to do this:

```
const counter = await Counter.findOne({ type: "Customer" });
// ...
await Counter.findOneAndUpdate({ type: "Customer" }, { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } });
```

...because it creates a race condition: overlapping asynchronous operations can both get the same sequence value and then both issue an update to it.

You want an atomic operation for incrementing and retrieving a new ID. I don't use MongoDB, but I *think* the [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) operation can do that for you if you add the `returnNewDocument` option. If so, the minimal change would be to swap over to using that:

```
const promises2 = customers.map(async customer => {
  if (!customer.customerId) {
    const counter = await Counter.findOneAndUpdate(
      { type: "Customer" },
      { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } },
      { returnNewDocument: true }
    );
    console.log({counter});
    const payload = {
      customerId: counter.sequence_value,
    };
    await Customer.create(payload);
  }
});
await Promise.all([...promises2]);
```

...but there's no reason to create an array and then immediately copy it, just use it directly:

```
await Promise.all(customers.map(async customer => {
  if (!customer.customerId) {
    const counter = await Counter.findOneAndUpdate(
      { type: "Customer" },
      { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } },
      { returnNewDocument: true }
    );
    console.log({counter});
    const payload = {
      customerId: counter.sequence_value,
    };
    await Customer.create(payload);
  }
}));
```

The overall operation will fail if anything fails, and only the first failure is reported back to your code (the other operations then continue and succeed or fail as the case may be). If you want to know everything that happened (which is probably useful in this case), you can use `allSettled` instead of `all`:

```
// Gets an array of {status, value/reason} objects
const results = await Promise.allSettled(customers.map(async customer => {
  if (!customer.customerId) {
    const counter = await Counter.findOneAndUpdate(
      { type: "Customer" },
      { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } },
      { returnNewDocument: true }
    );
    console.log({counter});
    const payload = {
      customerId: counter.sequence_value,
    };
    await Customer.create(payload);
  }
}));
const errors = results.filter(({status}) => status === "rejected").map(({reason}) => reason);
if (errors.length) {
  // Handle/report errors here
}
```

[`Promise.allSettled`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-allSettled) is new in ES2021, but easily polyfilled if needed.

If I'm mistaken about the above use of `findOneAndUpdate` in some way, I'm sure MongoDB gives you a way to get those IDs without a race condition. But in the worst case, you can pre-allocate the IDs instead, something like this:

```
// Allocate IDs (in series)
const ids = [];
for (const customer of customers) {
  if (!customer.customerId) {
    const counter = await Counter.findOne({ type: "Customer" });
    await Counter.findOneAndUpdate({ type: "Customer" }, { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } });
    ids.push(counter.sequence_value);
  }
}

// Create customers (in parallel)
const results = await Promise.allSettled(customers.map(async(customer, index) => {
  const customerId = ids[index];
  try {
    await Customer.create({
      customerId
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // Failed, remove the counter, but without allowing any error doing so to
    // shadow the error we're already handling
    try {
      await Counter.someDeleteMethodHere(/*...customerId...*/);
    } catch (e2) {
      // ...perhaps report `e2` here, but don't shadow `e`
    }
    throw e;
  }
});

// Get just the errors
const errors = results.filter(({status}) => status === "rejected").map(({reason}) => reason);
if (errors.length) {
  // Handle/report errors here
}
```

Comment: OMG!!! Amazing. I was just about to cry because of the issue, and was going to use `for loop` but This one clears almost all of my doubts. Thank you for this beauty and thanks for reading mongodb.

Comment: Hi T.J. Promise.all will fail if any of the operation inside it fails. I mean suppose I have to insert 5 documents and on the insertion of 3rd document some error come then the first 2 documents get inserted and the 4th & 5th does not. So what I have to do I want to 4th & 5th as well i.e. the ones which does not have any errors. Any suggestion. Here you can see https://jsfiddle.net/wkhroab8/

Comment: @Profer - You may want the new(ish) [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled), which waits for all promises to settle and then provides an array of the results. The results are objects with a `status` property which is either `"fulfilled"` or `"rejected"`. Objects for fulfilled promises have a `value` property with the result; objects for rejected promises have a `reason` property with the rejection reason. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the reply Then [**it**](https://jsfiddle.net/op47h9wk/) should give me the rejected single time when `array.length===1` but it is giving four times more. Why?

Comment: @Profer - Because `array.length === 1` is true four times, not just once. The first timer callback scheduled by `f2` pushes a value on the array, and then the other four see that the array has one thing in it and reject.

Answer (score -1):

Your map function is not returning a promise.

Try this :

```
const promises2 = [];

customers.map((customer) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    if (!customer.customerId) {
      const counter = await Counter.findOne({ type: 'Customer' });
      console.log({ counter });
      const payload = {
        customerId: counter.sequence_value,
      };
      await Customer.create(payload);
      await Counter.findOneAndUpdate({ type: 'Customer' }, { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } });
    }
    resolve();
  });
});

await Promise.all(promises2);
```

Comment: Please check the question. I have made my `map` function async. So no need to return `new Promise` again.